Train Yolo model for Coral dev board
I'm working on training a Yolo model for object detection and plan to use a Google Coral Dev Board for inference. As the Coral documentation recommends, the model should be in the TFLite format with 8-bit quantization for optimal performance.
Thanks to Ultralytics, exporting the model to the required format is straightforward:
Python
`
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("pre_trained_model.pt")
# Export the model to TFLite Edge TPU format
model.export(format="edgetpu")`
In the output, I see:
Number of operations that will run on Edge TPU: 425
Number of operations that will run on CPU: 24
My question is: Can I do anything to make all operations run on the TPU for faster processing?
Additionally, are there any other recommended models that might offer better accuracy and lower latency on a Google Coral board?
Thank you all.

Compile the model with the Edge TPU compiler, ensuring compatibility. And try using a smaller version of YOLO for easier to run on the Edge TPU.  For better accuracy and lower latency use SSD MobileNet V2 or EfficientDet-Lite.
